# How to turn on developer mode in magento 1.7?

Tags: debugging, magento

I go through [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics) tutorial and my problem consists in the fact that I do not get any function.include error on "The Global Config and Creating The Model" section (when assigning to a variable `Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost')`, while *the model doesn't exists yet*).

At some point I found in /index.php an if statement in which is called the following method:
`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` To test it, I put it outside the if statement (which I know is not good practice).

The result was that I got this warning message:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in /home/dowebro/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/home/dowebro/p...', 510, Array)
#1 /home/dowebro/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(510): simplexml_load_string('    loadString('    loadFile('/home/dowebro/p...')
#4 /home/dowebro/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesConfiguration(Array, Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config))
#5 /home/dowebro/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#6 /home/dowebro/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#7 /home/dowebro/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /home/dowebro/public_html/magento/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

but still no error which I would expect.

So, how can I get rid of this Warning message, but more important, how can I see errors in developement mode?

Thank you!

EDIT: While I go on with this tutorial, I see that I don't get any kind of feedback from core classes. Ex: I should get "Can't retrieve entity config: weblog/blogpost" while trying yo get data from a model of which resource definition is incomplete. Well, I don't. :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Developer mode is a sort of `use strict` for PHP and Magento.  It forces you to fix **everything**. If looks like the `simplexml_load_string` function doesn't like one of the XML configuration files in your system.  You can find out which one by going to line 510 in

```
/home/dowebro/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
```

and var dumping the variable that's being passed to `loadFile`.

Based on the error message

```
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

My guess is your `config.xml` XML prolog has some whitespace before it

```
[    ]<?xml version=...
```

or you've accidentally added a `<?` somewhere in your XML file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I went to Config.php, but that string is a huge one, and I can not figure out where to go from there. Regarding the config.xml, I have double checked it and it is ok.

Comment: I would still really want to get some feedback from Mage methods when something goes wrong. I can not do any debugging this way..

Comment: Alan, I took all the modules, again, and indeed there was a config.xml whose first tag had a space in front of it! Great "guess"! Thank you!

Comment: If you give me a hint on how to get those messages I mentioned, I would be grateful.

Comment: Oh, it was also in /index.php a ini_set('display_errors', 1); Now I get what I expected :)

Comment: Using trim `$xml = simplexml_load_string(trim($string), $this->_elementClass);` solved my problem thanks @Storm

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my post got deleted.
Mods I can't even message you back.

I followed the same tutorial as @Michael did and encountered the same problem.

The solution is going to root of application index.php and remove hash from the front of below statement

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1)
```

to

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and i can solve debugging  the file app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php

In this class search the metod   loadModulesConfiguration and im sure that you have the following code:

```
foreach ($fileName as $configFile) {
    $configFile = $this->getModuleDir('etc', $modName).DS.$configFile;
    if ($mergeModel->loadFile($configFile)) {
         $mergeToObject->extend($mergeModel, true);
    }
}
```

And  this add a block try catch like this :

```
foreach ($fileName as $configFile) {
    try {
        $configFile = $this->getModuleDir('etc', $modName).DS.$configFile;
        if ($mergeModel->loadFile($configFile)) {
            $mergeToObject->extend($mergeModel, true);
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($configFile);
    }
 }
```

And then check the log and you will have the name of the file that is the problem